# Generalizations of topos theory.

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

Is there a generalisation for topos theory? If so; then can you define that particular generalisation in brevity?

Comment: I am not sure what you are after. More general objects than toposes? There are many interesting ones, and the kind of trivial answer would be "categories". We can also take it into the direction of higher category theory with for example [(infinity, 1)-toposes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/(infinity,1)-topos).

Comment: @MarkKamsma Yes; i am after more general objects than toposes sir.

Comment: I just gave you a few. Can you specify what you expect from these objects? What do you want them to do? As it is, your question is too broad.

Comment: @MarkKamsma I was hoping for a generalisation that would allow an escape from causality.

Comment: Escape from what causality?

Comment: @MarkKamsma Causality in general sir. The causality in physics and hence in mathematics.

Comment: @MarkKamsma Sorry sir. I just noticed you gave examples of the generalizations for topos theory in your first comment. Thank you. Sorry for any inconvenience sir.

Comment: Deductive system.

Answer (score 3):

A topos is a special kind of category, so really the notion of a category generalizes the notion of a topos.

Slightly less tongue-in-cheek, a (elementary) topos is a [Cartesian Closed Category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category), with all Finite Colimits, and a [Subobject Classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subobject_classifier).

As such, Cartesian Closed Categories are a nice generalization of toposes, even moreso are the Cocomplete Cartesian Closed Categories.

---

In general, toposes let us interpret all of (intuitionistic) First Order Logic inside them. If we restrict to any fragment of iFOL we will get a new class of categories which contains the toposes, but contains more categories as well. These categories will be able to interpret some portion of iFOL inside them. For example:

- Finite Product Categories allow us to interpret equational structures
- Regular Categories allow us to interpret "regular logic"
- Coherent Categories allow us to interpret "coherent logic"

For an overview of these ideas, see Steve Awodey's lecture notes [here](https://github.com/awodey/CatLogNotes)

---

I hope this helps ^_^